# How to hide address bar any browser main page, using javascript? not on a new windows.open

Tags: javascript, php

I have a exam on html with php, and i just want disable the address bar and even make it on a full size.

May i change it before the login but, i dont know how to do that by php.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Hit F11.. There is no other way to do this.